# Javascript rendered hangout button not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, mobile, google-hangouts, hangouts-api

I'm trying to add a sort of "contact me" hangout button on my webpage.
The button is working fine on desktop. However on mobile (android phone or ipad) I get the message that I'm unable to join the session also the option to invite people is greyed out.

The code is pretty basic/standard

```
gapi.hangout.render("myDIV", { 'render': 'createhangout','widget_size': 72,
        'invites': [{id: "....@gmail.com",invite_type: "EMAIL"}]
    });
```

When in on desktop the hangout button opens a popup where my email adres is in the default invitees list. And I just press invite again and the hangout starts.

On mobile I see that no invitees are added and when I press on  join session it says unable to join with no more information about the cause.

Answer (score 0):

I'm testing same buttons for contact me. Works perfect on windows/mac in IE/Chrome/Firefox
But doesn't work on Android (Tablet or phone) nor on Ipad/iphone
On android hangouts starts and stops with an error on iOS it askes to invite people to the hangout but original invitee is not added
Tested with Chrome  on Android and Chrome and Safari on iOS